# Why won't images display in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written a short HTML file containing a HTML5 canvas, but when I run it the canvas is blank. There should be a red square. I've tried double clicking on the file so that it runs in Firefox and running it in the VS code live server.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
        #gameScreen {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        img {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="gameScreen" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  <script>
    let canv = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
    let ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(40, 40, 0, 20);
    ctx.fillStyle = #ff0000;
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Three issues...

- `#ff0000` should be in quotes.
- `fillStyle` should be before `fillRect`
- [`fillRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) is `(x, y, width, height)`... so `0` width won't show anything.

See this amended version...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
        #gameScreen {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        img {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="gameScreen" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  <script>
    let canv = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
    let ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.fillRect(40, 40, 20, 20);
  </script>
</body
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I actually created this snippet of code as a demonstration because HTML5 canvas won't work in a folder that is too large to show here that I downloaded from a youtube tutorial. I still can't get that code to work.

Comment: @Urthona26 - I'm glad the snippet works, but there is little I can do for code I cannot see. I answered the question you put in front of everybody

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to draw:

```js
ctx.fillRect(40, 40, 0, 20);
```

Where the `0` means, the `rect` has `0px` width, so yea, the'res nothing to see.

Consider changing to

```
ctx.fillRect(40, 40, 20, 20);
```

To get a `20x20` rect.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
        #gameScreen {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        img {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="gameScreen" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
  <script>
    let canv = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
    let ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.fillRect(40, 40, 20, 20);
  </script>
</body
```

---

Ps; `#ff0000` is a string and should be quoted:

```js
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
```